# GitHub APIでレポジトリ内のコメント一覧を取得する方法について

Tags: api, github

例えば、
以下のレポジトリのプルリクエスト内のコメント一覧を取得したいのですが、
https://github.com/github/orchestrator/

このようなコメントを取得する場合は、
https://github.com/github/orchestrator/issues/20#issuecomment-289201927
https://api.github.com/repos/github/orchestrator/issues/comments?since=2017-03-25

このようなレビューコメントを取得する場合は、
https://github.com/github/orchestrator/pull/102#discussion_r106798941
https://api.github.com/repos/github/orchestrator/pulls/comments?since=2017-03-18

なのかなと思っているのですが、

例えば、ここの
https://github.com/github/orchestrator/pull/115
`feel free to merge`のような一覧はどうやれば取得できるのでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

追記。
上記のsinceは例えのコメントを見つけやすくするように適当に振ってます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pull-Requestのレビューを拾ってくるAPIがあるのでそれを使って見るのはどうでしょうか。

https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/reviews/#list-reviews-on-a-pull-request

Comment: tell k さん できました。ありがとうございます。
`curl https://api.github.com/repos/github/orchestrator/pulls/115/reviews \-H "Accept: application/vnd.github.black-cat-preview+json"`
numberが不要だと良かったのですが、仕様みたいなのでそこはしょうがないですかね。

Comment: そうですね。その仕様を見る限りでは必ず pull requestの番号が必要になりそうです。